# does google negatively rank a page

Tags: web, seo

I am creating a website which is not completed yet. Somebody suggested me to put up some dummy pages on the  site so that google confides in it and the page rank could improve if the site is there for a while.

But if i do not change the contents and keep the website stagnant, will then google negatively rank the website?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a programming question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not advised to create empty dummy pages. If you have a little content that is actually related to what's going to be in the page that's ok, but pages with 'under construction' or 'coming soon' really don't help anything.

Matt Cutts from Google had something interesting to say about this, looking for it but I haven't found it yet.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely no! Better do have a little content which will be relevant actual subject of the website in future. But putting up 'under construction' pages will not be considered  by Google.